# Codeigniter return a message to view from controller trouble

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm trying to push a message when I insert data in my database with `add_message("message",'success/danger');` Im not getting anything even when the query is adding data in DB.

Controller:

```
function add_nino() {

    $id_representante_submit = (int) $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);

    if ($id_representante_submit > 0) {

        $representante_data['id_representante'] = $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_nino'] = $this->input->post('nino', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_parentesco'] = $this->input->post('parentesco', TRUE);

        $result = $this->representante->add_nino($representante_data);

        if($result){
            add_message("Test", 'success');
        } else {
            add_message("Test1", 'danger');
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('representante/add_nino_repre');
}
```

Model:

```
function add_nino($representante_data) {

    $this->db->insert('nino_padre', $representante_data);

}
```

Comment: is `add_message()` an internal Codeigniter function? where is it defined?

Comment: I think your looking for a flash message ?

Comment: I already used add_message() in another function and it worked well.

Comment: Im looking something like that (flash message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model needs to return something. Try editing your **model** like this:

```
function add_nino($representante_data) {
    $this->db->insert('nino_padre', $representante_data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: and your **controller**

```
function add_nino() {

    $id_representante_submit = (int) $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);

    if ($id_representante_submit > 0) {

        $representante_data['id_representante'] = $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_nino'] = $this->input->post('nino', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_parentesco'] = $this->input->post('parentesco', TRUE);

        $result = $this->representante->add_nino($representante_data);

        if($result){
            $data = array("message" => "success"); //sets variables in $data
        } else {
            $data = array("message" => "danger"); //sets variables in $data
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('representante/add_nino_repre', $data); //passes variables to view
}
```

**View**: representante/add_nino_repre

```
<div>
    <?php
     if(isset($message)){
         echo $message;
     } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: well what are you trying to do with the message? as far as i know there is not internal `add_message()` in Codeigniter.. What are you trying to do with this message, maybe ill help you in other ways on how to achieve your goal

Comment: im trying to get an kind of alert when i send the data

Comment: do you understand what I did?

Comment: i see what you did, im not sure what to do in the view, sorry im really new with codeigniter. if you can explain me a lil bit what to do with that data in the view please

Comment: I added another line to my answer.. Since you are passing an array called `$data` to your view. Your view will transform each key inside that `$data` array as a variable. Your `$data` array has a key of "message" , therefore the view will see that as a variable named `$message`

Comment: one more question man, is there any way to pass data with a redirect()? i mean, i want to redirect to another view after he show me the alert and save in the db

Comment: no the redirect() will not pass data.. but there may be other ways. What data do you want to pass to your "redirected" page?

Comment: i want to do this... if the alert i press send and it save in the db, show the success aler and redirect me to the index method, if not, show me the error alert and stay in the add_nino view.

Comment: i want to do this... if  i press send and it save in the db, show the success aler and redirect me to the index method, if not, show me the error alert and stay in the add_nino view.

Comment: pd: sorry my terrible english btw

Comment: no problem, your english is good.. i think for what you want you need AJAX.. I can help you remotely if you want, do you know how to use Teamviewer?

Comment: i cant use TV atm, im at my university and im not allowed to install programs here. if you just can tell any easy way to do this ill apreciate it. thanks a lot man

Comment: You could also show a particular website (complete with message) and add a meta tag in your head section: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?=base_url('success/danger'); ?>">` which will redirect to the `success/danger` controller after 5 seconds (of the number you specify in the page). You could even use Javascript (`window.location.replace` and `window.location.href`).

Comment: I did it just the way you said, with Javascript using location.href after clicking OK in the alert. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add alerts as you are saying than its probably best to work with jquery:

your JS in your view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        var url = "myapp.com/index.php/add_nino";
        var postdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result === "success") {
                location.href = "some other url";
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and your controller:

```
function add_nino() {

    $id_representante_submit = (int) $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);

    if ($id_representante_submit > 0) {

        $representante_data['id_representante'] = $this->input->post('id_representante', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_nino'] = $this->input->post('nino', TRUE);
        $representante_data['id_parentesco'] = $this->input->post('parentesco', TRUE);

        $result = $this->representante->add_nino($representante_data);

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "danger";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the idea of another HTTP request just for showing a message. Wouldn't it be better to show the message and redirect after some seconds?

Comment: well the structure he wants is the following: Start in his view -> submit the form (HTTP Req) -> save to DB -> if success alert and go to other page -> if error stay on page.. what  do you mean by "another HTTP request" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Godie, i did it with Javascript but you helped me a lot. Again thank you